# How to re-execute jQuery when screen sizes change

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im trying to do some minor edits when a particular screen size has been met. This works but only when the browser first loads. My code so far:

```
   if(vwo_$(window).width() >= 979){
    vwo_$('.move_cart_here').removeClass('span4');
    vwo_$('#sns_topheader .span12.topheader-left').removeClass('span8');
  };
  if(vwo_$(window).width() <= 978){
    vwo_$("#sns_header .container .row-fluid .header-right").append(vwo_$("#header_icons"));
  };
```

If anyone knows how this would "reload" every time the screen size changes in a controlled matter it would greatly help.

Comment: $(window).on('resize',function(){ })

Comment: this question has nothing to do with jQuery

Answer (score 2):

Just bind resize event on window:

```
$(window).on('resize', function(){ ... });
```

**EDIT:**
Assuming that the *jQuery* var is `vwo_$`, you might use:

```
vwo_$(window).on('resize', function() { (your logic here...) });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `.resize()` event handler to catch and event when ever the window is resized http://api.jquery.com/resize/ for exmaple:

```
$(window).resize(function (){
  if(vwo_$(window).width() >= 979){
    vwo_$('.move_cart_here').removeClass('span4');
    vwo_$('#sns_topheader .span12.topheader-left').removeClass('span8');
  };
  if(vwo_$(window).width() <= 978){
   vwo_$("#sns_header .container .row-fluid .header-right").append(vwo_$("#header_icons"));
  };
});
```

Comment: using this without the `on` method with custom namespace is not advised. this shows lack of understanding

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){
$(window).on('resize', function(){

if(vwo_$(window).width() >= 979){
    vwo_$('.move_cart_here').removeClass('span4');
    vwo_$('#sns_topheader .span12.topheader-left').removeClass('span8');
  };
  if(vwo_$(window).width() <= 978){
    vwo_$("#sns_header .container .row-fluid .header-right").append(vwo_$("#header_icons"));
  };

});
$(window).resize(); // for first time
});
```

Comment: your `if` statement is horrible. just use `else`, there is not need to write 2 `if`s. also, you do not check if a condition has happened already and you re-do the same code every time. this isn't such a simple question as you may think.